# why do I get "Segmentation fault" when assigning values to array of pointers

Tags: c

I have this peace of C Programming code to take multiple literal strings from the user and store each address to each pointer and print out the value

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *ptr[3];
    int i = 0;

    for (; i < 3; i++) {
        printf("ptr_%d:  ", i + 1);
        fgets(ptr[i], 15, stdin);
        ptr[i][strlen(ptr[i]) - 1] = 0;
        puts(ptr[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

However, only the first one is printed. Here is the output

```
ptr_1:  first line
first line
Segmentation fault

[Program finished]
```

I want the same result that is produced Here

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *ptr[] = {
        "first line", 
        "second line", 
        "third line"
    };

    puts(ptr[0]);
    puts(ptr[1]);
    puts(ptr[2]);
        
    return 0;
}
```

output

```
first line
second line
third line

[Program finished]
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: fgets needs an actual buffer of bytes to put the input into. Right now you're just handing it an uninitialized Pointer, which means it's going to write the input bytes to random places in memory

Comment: need to  allocate for `char *ptr[3]`

Comment: Or declare as an array of arrays: `char ptr[3][15]` (though then the name is no longer very approriate).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd probably want to put the scanf section of this code into a function but here is the smallest change to your existing sample that should work.

```
$ cat allocinput.c 

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_LEN 80

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        char c;
    char ptr[3][MAX_LEN];
    int i = 0;

for (;i<3;i++) {
    printf("ptr_%d:  ", i + 1);
    // could overflow if the user types more than MAX_LEN characters
    char *p = ptr[i];
    while (scanf("%c", &c) && (p - ptr[i] < MAX_LEN)) {
        if (c == '\n') break;
        *p++ = c;
        *p = 0;
        }
    puts(ptr[i]);
}

return 0;}
$ gcc -Wall allocinput.c 
$ ./a.out
ptr_1:  first line
first line
ptr_2:  second line
second line
ptr_3:  third line
third line
$
```

P.S. I recommend astyle to clean up the formatting:

```
$ astyle allocinput.c 
Formatted  /tmp/overflow/allocinput.c
$ cat allocinput.c

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_LEN 80

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char c;
    char ptr[3][MAX_LEN];
    int i = 0;

    for (; i<3; i++) {
        printf("ptr_%d:  ", i + 1);
        // could overflow if the user types more than MAX_LEN characters
        char *p = ptr[i];
        while (scanf("%c", &c) && (p - ptr[i] < MAX_LEN)) {
            if (c == '\n') break;
            *p++ = c;
            *p = 0;
        }
        puts(ptr[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
fgets(ptr[i], 15, stdin);
```

You've declared an array of three pointers:

```
char *ptr[3];
```

But none of those actually point to buffers of memory.

You can either create those buffers automatically:

```
char ptr[3][15];
```

Or dynamically with `malloc`.

```
char *ptr[3];

for (size_t i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    ptr[i] = malloc(15);
}
```

If you do this, make sure to `free` the memory you've allocated.

Comment: Thanks, this made it work. I was missing the allocation part. Marking as solved.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running gcc (with glibc 2.7 or greater), you can use the m modifier with `scanf` to allocate memory:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *ptr[3];

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        printf("ptr_%d:  ", i + 1);
        while (scanf(" %m[^\n]",&ptr[i]) != 1)
            printf("Try again: ");
        puts(ptr[i]);
    }

    for (; i < 3; i++)
        free(ptr[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

And be sure to `free` the memory when you are done with it.

Comment: check `errno` to make sure scanf allocated successfully

Comment: @long.kl The OP was using `fget`, so `%m[^\n]` gives the most similar behavior (spaces allowed)